# Check if PowerShell 5 is installed and if not install it via Chocolatey

Tags: windows, powershell, updates

I have a script in which I want to check if Powershell 5 is installed and if not then install it via Chocolaty. I believe an `if` statement is needed. Is there an easy way to check if PowerShell is updated and if not run this command?

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unresricted
iex ((New-Object 
System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
choco install powershell -y
choco upgrade powershell -y
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to check the version:

```
If ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 5) {
    iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
    choco install powershell -y
    choco upgrade powershell -y
}
```

I believe you'll need to change the Execution Policy from outside of the script for it to be both effective and non-interactive. Do that by running the script as follows:

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File yourscript.ps1
```